# Maximize the sum of numbers subject to an upper bound on their sum of squares

Tags: optimization

I want to find a maximum for $\sum_i^n x_i$ subject to $\sum_i^n x_i^2 \leq c$, where c is some constant.

I've done some searching and that's hinted at using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I  don't yet see how to use it here.

Comment: Hint: write $x_i=x_i\cdot 1$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use AM-QM inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys; I smacked myself on the forehead when I saw these!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \left\lvert \sum_i 1x_i \right\rvert^2 \leqslant \left( \sum_i 1 \right) \left( \sum_i x_i^2 \right) \leqslant nc, $$
applying Cauchy-Schwarz. Equality occurs precisely when the vectors $(1,1,\dotsc,1)$ and $(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)$ are parallel. It's easy after that.

Comment: Thanks Chappers.  Just one minor clarification; shouldn't the equality on the right be a $\leqslant$ as well?

Comment: Yeah, probably...