# Maximize sum of numbers subject to an upper bound of the sum of each of these numbers raised to an arbitrary power

Tags: optimization

I want to find a maximum for $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ subject to $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^{\alpha} \leqslant c$ where $c > 0$, $x_i > 0$ and $\alpha$ is a positive number greater than zero and not equal to 1.

This is an extension to my previous question found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489184/maximize-the-sum-of-numbers-subject-to-an-upper-bound-on-their-sum-of-squares) which involved finding a solution when when $\alpha = 2$ by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: There are going to be different scenarios for $\alpha<1$ and $\alpha>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha > 1$, the feasible region is convex.  By symmetry the maximum
will occur at a point where all $x_i$ are equal, namely $x_i = (c/n)^{1/\alpha}$.

If $\alpha < 1$, the function $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha$ is concave on 
$\{x: x_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = s\}$.  It follows that the maximum
(if you allow $x_i \ge 0$ rather than $> 0$) will occur at an extreme point, namely one $x_i = c^{1/\alpha}$, the others $0$.  If you insist on $x_i > 0$, there is no maximum but you can get arbitrarily close to $c^{1/\alpha}$.