# Intuition about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and optimization problems

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to develop intuition about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Suppose I have positive real vectors **x** and **y**.  The values of **x** are already determined and I want to find the values of **y** that maximize $\sum_i x_iy_i$ subject to $\sum_i y_i^2 \leqslant c$, where $c$ is some constant.  For these kinds of problems, I'm usually pointed to Cauchy-Schwarz.

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I can write the following:

$(\sum_i x_iy_i)^2 \leqslant (\sum_i x_i^2)(\sum_i y_i^2)$

At this point I'm unsure of how to proceed.  In a related question that I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489184/maximize-the-sum-of-numbers-subject-to-an-upper-bound-on-their-sum-of-squares), it was suggested that I find the values for which equality holds in Cauchy-Schwarz; I am still not sure why, though.  Does equality in Cauchy-Schwarz suggest that the left-hand side has been maximized?  If so, I do not see why.

In this case, equality holds when there is some constant $k$ such that $x_i/y_i = k$ for all $i$.  Once I've defined  $y_i$ in such a way that equality holds in Cauchy-Schwarz, I would substitute that expression into $\sum_i y_i^2 = c$ and solve for the value of interest in terms of $c$.  This will yield the parameters that maximize $\sum_i y_i^2$ (and thus, maximize $\sum_i x_iy_i$) subject to the upper bound $c$.

Does this approach make sense and, if so, why is it that we use the values of $y_i$ where equality holds in Cauchy-Schwarz?  I don't yet understand the implications of equality in Cauchy-Schwarz.